# Telebot Проверка на пересланные сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем привет, может кто подсказать как сделать проверку на то является ли сообщение пересланным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if message.forward_from != None:
```

или

```
if message.reply_to_message != None:
```

Answer (score 0):

`if message.forward_date != None:`
Отныне только так и никак иначе ибо если пользователь телеграма в настройках приватности запретил, то forward_from выдаст None в любом случае